# passing reference of angular 5 component to angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have made a directive in angular 5 which uses ngTemplateOutlet, thus my directive then requires the name of a component, which it then renders dynamically.

```
<back-container [componentOutlet]='dynamicComponent' [componentOutletContext]="{'data' : data}"></back-container>
```

Now this directive i am using in a component, which takes the reference of the component to be rendered as input.

```
<tile [dynamicComponent]='instance>
```

where instance is

```
instance = SpeedometerComponent;
```

This component i want to use in angular js application, thus i am using downgradeComponent to downgrade the component and use it in angular js.

```
.directive(
  'Tile',
  downgradeComponent({ component: TileComponent }) as angular.IDirectiveFactory)
```

How to pass component as an input in angular js application?
The component which i have to pass in angular js is another angular 5 component